# Curve start and end mapping don't work

Tags: bezier-curves

I was making a simple logo animation, and I wanted a curve to appear with the Start/End Mapping option, but when I try doing it, nothing happens. When I do try it with other curves it works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a curve is set to cyclic, the Start/End Mapping option doesn't make a difference, you have to switch it to non-cyclic for it to work. I haven't found any workaround for this yet, so setting the end and start of the curve really near each other may be the only option.